# Pandas six month resampling - user age/gender/plays data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to optimize a visualization that's way too crammed with annual data per below.

Here is a cut from my `usa_signup_age` dataframe:

```
          gender age
signup      
2002-10-29  m   31.0
2002-10-29  m   23.0
2002-10-29  m   23.0
2002-11-22  m   29.0
2002-11-28  m   25.0
2002-12-02  m   31.0
2003-02-06  m   29.0
2003-02-06  m   25.0
2003-02-06  m   25.0
2003-02-06  m   42.0
```

My aim is to calculage mean age of males vs females visualized in six month intervals to reduce overplotting.

```
usa_signup_age.groupby('gender')['age'].plot(legend=True)
plt.xlabel('years')
plt.ylabel('age by gender')
plt.title('total signup ages per gender per year')
plt.show()
```

Is there such thing as a `'6M'` parameter for the `resample()` method?

Comment: usa_signup_age.groupby('gender')['age'].mean()?

Comment: `df.groupby('gender').resample('6m').mean()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.Grouper()` for custom grouping, and then apply more grouping using `.apply()` on top of that. This is very handy for datetime objects. After converting your `signup` variable to datetime using `pd.to_datetime()` you can do:

```
usa_signup_age.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(key="signup", freq="6M")).apply(lambda x: x.groupby('gender').mean())
```

This will return:

```
                         age
signup     gender
2002-10-31 m       25.666667
2003-04-30 m       29.428571
```

Comment: here's what i got, the grouping of data is far cleaner now, but i lost my separation of male vs female grouping...`usa_signup_age['signup'] = pd.to_datetime(usa_signup_age.index)
usa_signup_age.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='signup', freq="6M")).mean().plot(legend=True)`

Comment: @Mr.Jibz My bad, I forgot to split by gender, updating the solution right now.

Comment: how would i make this a bar chart? `plot(kind='bar')`?

Comment: @Mr.Jibz There are multiple ways to do that, `df.plot` would work, or you can use `plt.bar` or `seaborn` library.